# JSON objects to array conversion

Tags: php, typo3-extensions

I have a multidimensional array assigned to single variable 'data'. I prepared array as follows:

```
$img1 = [
    'title' => 'example',
    'description' => 'description'
];
$imagesArray[] = [
     'img1' => [
        'normal' => $img1
     ]
 ];
$data = [
     'data' => [
        'images' => $imagesArray
    ],
    'message' => 'OK'
 ];
```

When encode it as JSON array, following output is produced.

```
{
    "images":{
        "normal":{
            {
            "title" : "example1",
            "description" : "description1"
            },
            {
            "title" : "example2",
            "description" : "description2"
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

But I require following output:

```
{
    "images":[
        "normal":[
            [
            "title" : "example1",
            "description" : "description1"
            ],
            [
            "title" : "example2",
            "description" : "description2"
            ]
        ]
    ]
 }
```

Do anyone have solution? ..Thanks in advance

Comment: `json_encode` don't produce your example output - there aren't `=>` in json, only `:`. And your second example is also a complete mess. Are you sure about the output format? I didn't know any format which mixes `=>` and `:` and uses one time `[]` and the other time `{}`.

Comment: _“But I require following output:”_ - that is not even valid JSON. Apart from the `=>` issue, you can not have such associative keys in a JavaScript array, if you want those keys, then you _must_ use objects in those places.

Comment: Forgive me  for placing "=>" instead of ":". I have replaced the code.

Answer (score 1):

The output you want may be the java-script object/array but this is not a valid `JSON`output. You can check output you want in https://jsonlint.com.

Your final data array should be

```
     $data = [
                'images' => [
                    [
                        'normal' => [
                            [
                                [
                                    'title' => 'example1'
                                ],
                                [
                                    'description' => 'description1'
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                [
                                    'title' => 'example2'
                                ],
                                [
                                    'description' => 'description2'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ];
```

and this will convert array to JSON like

```
{
    "images": [
        {
            "normal": [
                [
                    {
                        "title": "example1"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "description1"
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "title": "example2"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "description2"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```